# How to resolve Uncaught Error:29.0.0 in React Native Expo project

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, expo

I am trying out a demo of a `react-native application` that was built (not by me) using Expo approach. After installing dependencies and trying to run the application; I get the error below:

> Uncaught Error: 29.0.0 is not a valid SDK version. Options are 35.0.0 , 33.0.0, UNVERSIONED. `16:56:55 Fatal Error`.

Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "food-shop",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^29.0.0",
    "expokit": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.2"
  }
}
```

I am using Huawei Y5 Lite, Android 8.1.0. What I wish to know is,how can I resolve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your `package.json` for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of the Expo app only supports SDK 33+

https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-35-is-now-available-beee0dfafbf4

> We routinely drop SDK versions that have low usage, but we’ve dropped more versions than usual with this release. SDK 33 was the first version that included 64-bit support, and in order for us to update the Expo client on Google Play, every SDK version we include must have 64-bit support.
>   This release sees the end of life for SDKs 31 and 32. As usual, your standalone apps built with these SDK versions will continue to work; however, SDK 31 and 32 projects will no longer work within the latest version of Expo Client.
>   At this time, you can still run expo build for SDK 31 and 32 projects. Note, however, that you must upgrade to 33 or later in order to submit an updated APK to Google Play due to the 64-bit requirement. We will remove support for SDKs 31 and 32 in expo build in a future release.
>   If you still need to test a project running SDK 31 or 32, you can download this Android client version and this iOS client version.

You won’t be able to run that app unless you update the sdk to a more recent one.

Comment: I am getting this error, Unsupported SDK version: our app builders don't have support for 33.0.0 version yet. Submitting the app to the Apple App Store may result in an unexpected behaviour
Unsupported SDK version

Comment: @tksilicon Expo 37 was released today. As part of that release support for the Expo 33 SDK was dropped, this is probably why you are experiencing problems. You will probably need to update the SDK version of your app, I would suggest to SDK 37 so that you don't have to upgrade again for some time. You can read more about the latest release [here](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-37-is-now-available-dd5770f066a6)